# OS with file manager and web browser only

Tags: operating-system

I'm looking for an OS that has only a file manager, and a web browser; i.e. as least bloatware as possible.

What is the best OS like that?

Comment: Wyse Terminal...

Comment: For what kind of computer/architecture? May it cost something? Does it need to have a GUI?

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, nothing beats https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS

Chrome OS is an operating system designed by Google that is based on the Linux kernel and uses the Google Chrome web browser as its principal user interface. As a result, Chrome OS primarily supports web applications.

Comment: Nevermind. I'll make a new post.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Booby, that ChromeOs is a good bet, for simplicity.

Other alternatives would be one of the smaller Linux Distros, such as :

- [image] [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm)(a little over 100***m***B (not gB), loads quickly & runs happily form a USB stick)
- [image] [Damn small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) is even smaller at 50mB, and offers the same functionality
- any other [lightweight Linux Distro](http://www.techradar.com/news/10-of-the-best-lightweight-linux-distros)

These have the advantage of running very well on older, lower spec’d machines, an advantage over ChromeOs.

For complete control, Google for "build your own Linux distro", for instance [image] [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). There are quite a few systems which let you choose components simply by ticking a few check boxes (I like [image] [Suse Studio](https://susestudio.com/), where you specify what you want, in the browser, and it generates a distro for you).

And, for the ultimate control, it can be a lot of fun to try [Gentoo Linux](https://gentoo.org/), which lets you select components and compile each one to truly build your Linux from scratch.

You pays your zer0 eurodollars and you takes your choice.

(sorry about the logos, I got carried away :-)