# Operating system for web browsing for non technical user with near zero computer experience

Tags: web-browser, web, operating-system, malware

tl;dr - what OS do you suggest for only web browsing for actual PC newbies (that have like near zero experience when it comes to computers and web browsing) that does not require tons of configuration (so kind of out of the box) and is less likely to get any sort of malware/virus/etc. while using it?

Longer version:

I'm planning on buying a laptop for web browsing only for my parents (my company is selling used laptops cheap so I want to use this occasion). But my parents have like near zero experience when it comes to computers overall (which at some degree is a plus, they aren't used to any OS GUI) so browsing the web might result in getting some kind of malwares, etc. I can't be 100% times next to them when they want to use and browse it more consciously (like checking the links, checking what I'm clicking etc.). As much as this would not be a huge problem to just reinstall the whole OS again (aside from some kind of BIOS/UEFI rootkit that even after a reinstall would persist on the hardware) this might be a potential threat for other PC on my local network (can't use vlans here due to lack of hardware and I'm not really knowledgeable enough when it comes to networking). Plus doing it often is annoying (even if I would make a clonezilla image and then just restore everything, it still requires time).

So which OS should I use that will minimize the chances of getting a malware/virus/etc. while browsing the net, that doesn't require tons of configuration?

Also second question (if Linux would be the suggestion) - should I install antivirus software there (if yes - which?)?

As additional info - I plan to install there all sort of NoScript/Disable popups/adblockers/https everywhere to disable most of "annoying" stuff for them, setup a standard user without root/admin access, etc. This PC won't be used to browse mailboxes, social medias, bank accounts and so on that requires any authentication.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OS with file manager and web browser only](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/40222/os-with-file-manager-and-web-browser-only)

Comment: I'll agree with the second answer: linux, as most malware is aimed at windows. I'd just add an aside that if you aren't too worried about size there are some really sleek distros out there like [cute fish](https://cutefish-ubuntu.github.io)

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about this question, had too much stuff on my head. @Judith - nice, will check the distros from the 2nd post there (as I just don't like Chrome so using ChromeOS :D). Thanks.

Comment: @depperm - will check that also (size is not a problem). Thanks